# Issue in Grand Totals (Excel Pivot table)

Tags: ssas, excel-2010, pivot-table

I am working on an Excel pivot table that looks like the following:

```
Prj             30Days      60Days      GreaterThan60
128139          0           0           118484.02
123123          0           0           10115.01
234232          0           0           4609.81
121313          0           0           314.33
343432          0           0           4000
232323          0           0           164.27
121212          164994.98   0           0
232323          0           0           1046.58
Grand Total     1075731.89  535507.27   199200.01
```

Here is my expected/desired result:

```
Prj             30Days      60Days      GreaterThan60   GrandTotal
128139          0           0           118484.02       118484.02
123123          0           0           10115.01        10115.01
234232          0           0           4609.81         4609.81
121313          0           0           314.33          314.33
343432          0           0           4000            4000
232323          0           0           164.27          164.27
121212          164994.98   0           0               164994.98
232323          0           0           1046.58         1046.58
Grand Total     1075731.89  535507.27   199200.01       1810439.17
```

The `Grand Totals` at the bottom of the pivot table are `Grand Totals` for `columns`. I also need the `Grand Totals` for `Rows` as the right most `Column`. I am not able to do this, though I checked the option to `SET Grand Totals` for both rows and columns.

I researched this issue online and it says that we need to have at-least one field in Column Labels to get the Row Totals, I don't have a field that I want to put in the Column Labels.

Can I create a calculate measure to achieve this?  I looked into creating a calculated field in Excel under `PivotTable/Options/FieldItems` and `Sets/New Calculated Field`. But the `New Calculated Field` option is disabled.

Comment: based on your data, `30Days`, `60Days` and `GreaterThan60` are `Fields` containing `Values` marked in `FieldList` with summation character. These fields are different from `Prj` which doesn't contain values but `Items`. `GrandTotal` is calculated only for `Fields` that contain `Items` and not for `Values`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some more 'data' to match up with your totals. A PT with Grand Total for rows seems feasible:

[image: SO21105046 example]

Since you have tried what I used for the GT for rows without success I'm guessing your data input (not shown) must not be in the same format as in my example. If for example you have dates rather than the (credit period?) bands then using these dates to calculate the appropriate bands in  the source data may be all that you are missing.